# (SSRS) if cell contains specific text then divide another cell by a number say 2

Tags: reporting-services

I'm having trouble trying to divide a cell by (A NUMBER) only if another cell contains specific text and if the cell contains another text i want it to be divide by a different number in SSRS

This is what i have but it is not working.

```
=IIF(Fields!PARTNO_LOT.Value=("A1001"),Fields!LOCSTOCK.Value/200)
```

I have added a example but in excel just to show my intent in SSRS.         [image: HERE IS THE EXAMPLE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the above answer doesn't work, try this:

```
=Switch(
Fields!PARTNO_LOT.Value="A1001",Fields!LOCSTOCK.Value/200,
Fields!PARTNO_LOT.Value="A1002",Fields!LOCSTOCK.Value/285,
Fields!PARTNO_LOT.Value="A1003",Fields!LOCSTOCK.Value/89
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: THIS WORKED THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: If my answer solved your problem you can select it as correct by click on the right symbol in the left side of the answer. [How to select an answer as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly,  you are trying to execute multiple conditions.  You can use nested IIF statements:

```js
=IIF(Fields!PARTNO_LOT.Value=("A1001"),Fields!LOCSTOCK.Value/200,
    IIF(Fields!PARTNO_LOT.Value=("A1002"),Fields!LOCSTOCK.Value/285, Fields!LOCSTOCK.Value/89))
```

If your values are only few, this would work.  If they are more than 2-3, I would look into creating a function. Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028.aspx

Comment: I only have 3 Values, I am getting the below error when running SSRS The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox11.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter 'FalsePart' of 'Public Function IIf(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object) As Object'.

Comment: Yes i copy and pasted exactly.

Comment: I have not have a chance to run it in an actual report so it is possible that I missed a comma somewhere.  The IIF statement takes 3 parameters:  IIF(condition, true_part, false_part).  When nesting sometimes it can get messy.  alejandro zuleta's suggestion is a better option in this case.